# No property findAll found for type With Cassandra Entity

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

My custom repository is extending CassandraRepository

```
public interface CassandraRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> var1);

    List<T> findAll();

    List<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> var1);

    Slice<T> findAll(Pageable var1);

    <S extends T> S insert(S var1);

    <S extends T> List<S> insert(Iterable<S> var1);
}
```

and my Custom repository class is

```
@Repository
public interface BookManageRepository extends CassandraRepository<BookEntity, BookKey> {
 ...
}
```

And iam getting following Exception

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
    name 'bookManageRepository' defined in com.test.cassandra.repository.BookManageRepository 
    defined in @EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories declared on 
    CassandraReactiveRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: 
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type BookEntity!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
```

Getting Exception "No property findAll found for type", I dont have any Property **findAll** in my Entity

Using Springboot 2.3

This is my Book Entity

```
@Table("books")
public class BookEntity {
    
    @PrimaryKey
    private BookKey key;
    
    @Column("book_id")
    private String BookId;

    @Column("book_name")
    private String bookName;

    @Column("book_type")
    private String deviceType;

    @Column("created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    
    ...

}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.cassandra.repository"})
public class SpringDataCassandraConfig {

@Bean
public CqlSession session() {
    return CqlSession.builder().withKeyspace("mykeyspace").build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the annotation @Repository to your repository.
If you write your BookManageRepository like this, it should find the method "findAll()".

```
@Repository
public interface BookManageRepository extends CassandraRepository<BookEntity, BookKey> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It is not clear what is the structure of `BookKey` and so I have made it up as a composite key with a partition column and a clustering column

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class BookKey implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "book_number", ordinal = 0, 
    type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String bookNumber;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "book_code", ordinal = 1, 
    type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    private int bookCode;
```

**1. Book Enitity (same as in the question)**

```
@Table("books")
public class BookEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    private BookKey key;

    @Column("book_id")
    private String BookId;

    @Column("book_name")
    private String bookName;

    public BookEntity() {
    }

    public BookEntity(BookKey key, String bookId, String bookName) {
        this.key = key;
        BookId = bookId;
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public BookKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(BookKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getBookId() {
        return BookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(String bookId) {
        BookId = bookId;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

**2. My pom dependencies**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**3. DDL of the table created by spring data**

```
CREATE TABLE kavi.books (
    book_number text,
    book_code int,
    book_id text,
    book_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_number, book_code)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (book_code DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

**4. Application.properties**

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=kavi
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
```

**5. Spring Boot Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BookManageRepository bookManageRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        BookKey bookKey = new BookKey("book-number-1", 1);
        BookEntity book = new BookEntity(bookKey, "book-id-1", "book-name-1")
        bookManageRepository.save(book);
        bookManageRepository.findAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**6. I can confirm that it is saving the book as well as retrieving it without any issue. So it must be either you extending some `non spring data CassandraRepository` or you are missing something in your `BookKey` primary key class**

Comment: Thanks for you test class, I suspect with Springboot it default to EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories , even i am using  EnableCassandraRepositories

Comment: My example was based on Spring boot 1.5. I will update it to 2.3.1 as well. Thank you. your question was useful for me too